# Using SQL Server LEFT JOIN without multiple rows - how do I do that anyway?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables (`Items` and `Order` tables). A left join is all we need. I only want one row per `Item_No` which can be selected randomly (or top 1). How do I do that anyway? The expected output is presented in the bottom.

`items` table

```
Item_No   Item_com
-------------------
11        com10
11        com11
```

`Order` table:

```
Item_No   Order_on
-------------------
11        100
11        200
11        300
11        400
```

Expected output:

```
Item_No   Item_com   Order_on
-----------------------------
11        com10       100
11        com11       200
11        null        300
11        null        400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to line up the matching items from the two tables.  This is a bit tricky in SQL -- and this is not just a `left join`.  You need another field.  One way to generate the field is to use the ANSI standard `row_number()` function:

```
select o.*, i.item_com
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item_no order by item_no) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o left join
     (select i.*
             row_number() over (partition by item_no order by item_no) as seqnum
      from items i
     ) i
     on i.item_no = o.item_no and i.seqnum = o.seqnum;
```

Most databases support window functions (such as `row_number()`) including the latest release of MySQL (this was an original database tag).  In earlier versions, you have to make do with alternative solutions using variables or correlated subqueries or something like that.

Comment: Thank you

Your answer is 100%